# What can happen if a person violates a website's terms of service?

Tags: intellectual-property, terms-of-service

What could happen to a person if they violate a website's license? For example https://medialoot.com/member/license/ says you're not allowed to reuse their code, but if someone did what would happen to the person? Could they be ordered to take it down or be sued?

Has there been any real examples where a websites ToS or license made a difference in litigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Medialoot have an absolute right to decide how people use their code.

They can sue to have you to stop using their code, if you don't have a valid license to use it.

It doesn't matter if they don't suffer financial damage from you using the code, it is still illegal to use the code without a license from them.

[Here](https://opensource.com/law/14/7/lawsuit-threatens-break-new-ground-gpl-and-software-licensing-issues) is an example of litigation that involves a company using software available to the public, but breaking the terms of the license by not making the software open source. There were no damages but you can still be sued because medialoot have an absolute right to decide how people use their code

Answer (score 2):

They can seek an order requiring the offending material be taken down.

Many country's copyright law will also allow them to sue for [statutory damages](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statutory_damages_for_copyright_infringement) which does not require that there be any loss to the copyright holder or gain to the infringer.